# How to calculate time complexity for conditional statement and loops

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

The pseudocode is as below. how to calculate time complexity for this programme

```
Algorithm MinValue(A, n):

Input: An integer array A of size n //1
Output: The smallest value in A 

minValue <- A[0] //1
for k=1 to n-1 do //n
if (minValue > A[k]) then //n-1
minValue <- A[k] //1
return minValue  //1
```

so, it's 1+1+n+n-1+1+1 = 2n+3, is it correct?

---

This is a more simple programme
    Algorithm MaxInt(a, b):

```
Input: Two integers a and b //1
Output: The larger of the two integers 

if a > b then //1
return a //1
else 
return b. // 1
```

total operations = 4, is it correct?

Could anyone tell me the correct answer? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close.

In the first program, the number of times `minValue <- A[k]` is executed can be `n-1` at the worst case (if the numbers are sorted in descending order).

Therefore the total number of operations is bound by 1 + n-1 + n-1 + n-1 + 1 = 3*n-1 = O(n).

For the second program, either `return a` or `return b` is executed. Therefore the number of operations is 2 (the condition + the chosen return statement).

Answer (score 0):

Complexity of a conditional statement is maximum of complexities of the branches, plus complexity of the condition expression.